# What kind of cable do I need to connect MacBook Pro to iMac for display?

Tags: imac, display

I would like to use the iMac for external display and would like to connect MacBook Pro as a source. What kind of cable do I need and how to I setup the display?

Comment: It depends on which model MBP and iMac you have - use the System Profiler application under your Apple menu to get the exact models, then post those results.

Answer (score 1):

If the iMac has Thunderbolt (Mid-2011 and later models):

- The MBP must also have Thunderbolt
- Connect the two with a Thunderbolt cable and press Cmd-F2 on the iMac's keyboard

If the iMac doesn't have Thunderbolt:

- It must be a 27" model with a mini-Displayport connector (21" and 24" mini-Displayport models don't support Target Display mode).
- Any device with Displayport output can use it as a display.
- Connect the two with a Mini-DisplayPort to Mini-DisplayPort cable, and press Cmd-F2 on the iMac's keyboard

[Full documentation is available here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4469).